# -[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: message sent to deallocated instance?

Tags: ios, calendar

I am trying to implement calendar. I have one label for year and two buttons for incrementing and decrementing year from calendar. I am getting this exception

```
(-[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x147165f0)
```

while clicking button(increment or decrement)my requirement is if i click right button my year should increase as well as if i click left button my year should decrease. my exception line is

```
date = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear value:1 toDate:date options:0];
```

could you please help to resolve this issue. this is my code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        date = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
        NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        yar1.text=stringFromDate;

     }
    - (IBAction)right:(id)sender {

        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        date = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear value:1 toDate:date options:0];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
        NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        yar1.text=stringFromDate;

       }
 - (IBAction)left:(id)sender {

        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        date = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear value:1 toDate:date options:0];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
        NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        yar1.text=stringFromDate;

       }
```

Comment: What type of `@property` is `date` ?

Comment: the property of date is NSdate

Comment: Which type of property?

Comment: @ alex_izh the property type NSdate *date = [NSDate date];

Comment: @BathiBabu we are asking if it's a `weak/strong/retain/assign` property. How are you declaring it ?

Comment: @ KIDdAe @property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * date;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code looks fine and I tried in sample app, its working fine. Did you synthesize your date property? Also please cross check if your property is of type strong.

Comment: Yes,iam synthesized date  property.

Comment: property type? can you please copy paste your property declaration and synthesize code?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * date;

Comment: This code looks fine to me. But just for safe side, can you replace         date = [NSDate date];
with
        self.date = [NSDate date];

Comment: Can you post both .h and .m file code here? May be you are assigning nil to date somewhere else?